# How do I use the route package to push a new URL and trigger its handler?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

Here's my attempt:

https://github.com/DaveNotik/dart-stack/commit/99f877491dbd7163aa1bd8d5844c489bdab05eeb

My aim was to make it so when /welcome is detected (which I set the Facebook callback URL to) a window.alert is triggered. But right now it triggers on every page load, so it doesn't seem the router is working appropriately? Is my approach correct?

Comment: Can you please add the relevant code that allows to reproduce the problem to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you problem is this:

```dart
addHandler(Routes.sayWelcome, MainController.sayWelcome(app))
```

The second argument should be a function to call; but you are calling the function immediately such that its return value is being used as the handler. You need to make this a function so that it will be invoked only when the route is navigated to. For example:

```dart
addHandler(Routes.sayWelcome, (_) => MainController.sayWelcome(app))
```